# How to inherit animation properties while animating CALayer with implicit animation

Tags: ios, core-animation, calayer

I am trying to animate a custom property on a CALayer with an implicit animation:

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f animations:^{
    self.imageView.myLayer.myProperty = 1;
}];
```

In -actionForKey: method I need to return the animation taking care of interpolating the values. Of course I have to tell somehow the animation how to retrieve the other parameters for the animation (i.e. the **duration** and the **timing function**).

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event
{
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"myProperty"])
        {
            CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"myProperty"];
            [anim setFromValue:@(self.myProperty)];
            [anim setKeyPath:@"myProperty"];
            return anim;
        }
        return [super actionForKey:event];
    }
}
```

Any idea on how to achieve that? I tried looking for the animation in the layer properties but could not find anything interesting. I also have a problem with the layer animating since actionForKey: is called outside of animations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I reckon that you have a custom layer with you custom property "myProperty" that you added to the backing layer of UIView - according to the Documentation UIView animation blocks does not support the animation of custom layer properties and states the need to use CoreAnimation:

> Changing a view-owned layer is the same as changing the view itself,
>   and any animations you apply to the layer’s properties respect the
>   animation parameters of the current view-based animation block. The
>   same is not true for layers that you create yourself. Custom layer
>   objects ignore view-based animation block parameters and use the
>   default Core Animation parameters instead.
>
> If you want to customize the animation parameters for layers you
>   create, you must use Core Animation directly.

Further the documentation sates that UIView supports just a limited set of animatable properties
which are:

- frame
- bounds
- center
- transform
- alpha
- backgroundColor
- contentStretch

> Views support a basic set of animations that cover many common tasks.
>   For example, you can animate changes to properties of views or use
>   transition animations to replace one set of views with another.
>
> Table 4-1 lists the animatable properties—the properties that have
>   built-in animation support—of the UIView class.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewPG_iPhoneOS/AnimatingViews/AnimatingViews.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009503-CH6-SW12

You have to create a CABasicAnimation for that.

You can have sort of a workaround with CATransactions if you return a CABasicAnimation in actionForKey: like that

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
    [CATransaction begin];
    [CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];

    customLayer.myProperty = 1000; //whatever your property takes

    [CATransaction commit];
  }];
```

Just change your actionForKey: method to something like that

```
- (id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event
{
    if ([event isEqualToString:@"myProperty"])
    {
        return [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:event];
    }
    return [super actionForKey:event];
 }
```

There is something in Github in case you wan't to have a look: https://github.com/iMartinKiss/UIView-AnimatedProperty

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can access the **duration** if you use :

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:duration animations:^{
}];
```

Other issue with your code is, the implementation of actionForKey: of UIView only returns a CAAnimation object if the code is called inside an animation block. Otherwise it returns null to turn off animation. In your implementation, you always return a CAAnimation, hence changing to that property will always be animated.

You should use this :

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:duration];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:timingFunction];

customLayer.myProperty = 1000; //whatever your property takes

[CATransaction commit];
```

Then in your actionForKey: method, use `[CATransaction animationDuration]` and `[CATransaction animationTimingFunction]` to retrieve the current duration and timing function.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way could be onother property in the your custom layer to set **before** *myProperty*. like:

```
self.imageView.myLayer.myTimingFunction = kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut;
self.imageView.myLayer.myProperty = 1;
```

And

```
-(id<CAAction>)actionForKey:(NSString *)event
{
 if ([event isEqualToString:@"myProperty"])
    {
        CABasicAnimation *anim = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"myProperty"];
        [anim setFromValue:@(self.myProperty)];
        [anim setKeyPath:@"myProperty"];
        [anim setTimingFunction:myTimingFunction];
        return anim;
    }
    return [super actionForKey:event];
 }
}
```

If you want to get parameters, like **duration**, set in

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:2.0f ...
```

So in this case **duration = 2.0f**

you can use **CATransaction** and **valueForKey**. CATransaction should return the specific value of the context.

Comment: The problem is, I don't want to change the interface to the layer, that is the code accessing myProperty should just be aware of the property, not of the internals of CALayer subclass.