# Long-running animations in iOS (up to 1/2 hour)

Tags: ios7, core-animation

So I've got [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24603558/animated-pie-chart-that-can-animate-in-both-directions) animated pie chart working now. It can indicate e.g. progress over time (similar to `UIProgressView`).

For legacy reasons I am still using it with a timer that fires approx. every second and increases `progress`. It should now be possible to get rid of this timer and set the overall duration of a pie animation e.g. to 1/2 hour instead of letting the timer fire 30 * 60 times and starting as many short incremental animations.

So my question is this: are there any good reasons that speak against using such long (say up to 1/2 hour long) animations in iOS? In the example of the pie chart no more than approx. 360 frames would be needed even over 1/2 hour.

Comment: If it runs for that long, why don't you observe the progress and redraw when it changes? It sounds like it shouldn't be very frequently.

Comment: @DavidRönnqvist Observe with KVO and redraw when it changes? Isn't this what core animation does internally? I was interested in adding animation support to my pie view to reset its progress with (a short) animation. So I'm now wondering whether I can use the same mechanism for supporting longer animations too (and thereby remove some perhaps redundant code around an `NSTimer`.) It seems feasible; if it's a bad idea, then please why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a good reason against very long animations: memory.
`CoreAnimation` will create a `presentationLayer` for every frame (see for example [your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24597797/non-animatable-properties-in-subclasses-of-calayer)), and (at least up to iOS 7.1) it will allocate and initialize them in background the moment you add the animation to the layer.

*The frame rate depends on the device*, not on the magnitude of the change of the animated property; moreover, there doesn't seem to be a way to tweak `CoreAnimation`'s frame rate on iOS (while on OSX [`NSAnimation`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/cocoa/reference/applicationkit/Classes/NSAnimation_Class/Reference/Reference.html) has a `frameRate` property), so if you animate `progress` (but it would be the same with any property) and set a duration time of 30 minutes, you will end up with *a lot* of memory wasted.

**Some numbers**. I scheduled some `CABasicAnimation`s with path `progress` on your `DZRoundProgressLayer`, and added some logging in `-initWithLayer:`. This revealed that on the simulator, roughly 50 shadow copies (frames) are needed per second of animation.
This means *90K* shadow copies are going to be created for 30 minutes: for several seconds after the beginning of the animation, `CoreAnimation` was still allocating the first thousands of copies. Adding some data payload to the instance variables of `DZRoundProgressLayer` showed the memory usage raising by several MB in the first seconds (then some memory management took over the unconstrained allocations, presumably freeing the old copies).

**Is it a bad idea?** It's a waste of resources, memory and CPU, even if your layer occupies a few bytes in memory, considering that the change in the pie area per frame is too small to be noticed. Setting up a `NSTimer` or KVO doesn't require many lines of code, so it might be worth to change approach.

Comment: +1 Ok, that nails it: "frame rate depends on the device". (I thought I could perhaps set my own, i.e. very low one for long-running animations.) Thx esp. for the quantitative evidence.

Comment: Unfortunately on iOS frame rate is decided by `CoreAnimation`. It is reasonable to assume that it it synced with display's refresh rate (as you had to do [manually](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html) with OpenGL before iOS 5 introduced `GLKView`).

Comment: May I ask one more core-animation-related follow-up question: Is it possible to configure the by-now-animatable custom property `progress` such that animates when called from an animations block in `UIView animateWithDuration:animations:` and otherwise is does not (or perhaps animates with duration zero)? I can post this as a separate question, if necessary.

Comment: It has already been answered: [How to inherit animation properties with implicit animation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22405966/how-to-inherit-animation-properties-while-animating-calayer-with-implicit-animat); it is not possible without modifying the mechanism used for passing the `duration` parameter (for example by overriding `+animateWithDuration:animations:`.